# Problems with uitableview sections using JSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am creating an app for demo purposes and have a uitableview being populated with JSON data and it works fine. Now I want to create sections in the table based on the sessionDate but my app crashes with the error below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Sessions objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac2b460'

Here is the code for parsing the JSON:

```
-(void) retrieveData
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sessions-json.json" ofType:nil]];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //Set up our speakers array
    sessionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {
    //create sessions object
    NSString * sID = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * sStatus = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionStatus"];
    NSString * sDay = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionDay"];
    NSString * sDate = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionDate"];
    NSString * sTime = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionTime"];
    NSString * sName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionName"];
    NSString * sSpeaker1 = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionSpeaker1"];
    NSString * sSpeaker1Company = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"speaker1Company"];
    NSString * sSpeaker2 = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionSpeaker2"];
    NSString * sSpeaker2Company = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"speaker2Company"];
    NSString * sSpeaker3 = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionSpeaker3"];
    NSString * sSpeaker3Company = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"speaker3Company"];
    NSString * sSpeaker4 = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionSpeaker4"];
    NSString * sSpeaker4Company = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"speaker4Company"];
    NSString * sSpeaker5 = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionSpeaker5"];
    NSString * sSpeaker5Company = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"speaker5Company"];
    NSString * sSpeaker6 = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionSpeaker6"];
    NSString * sSpeaker6Company = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"speaker6Company"];
    NSString * sDesc = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionDesc"];
    NSString * sITSCECS = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ITSCECS"];
    NSString * sSessionID = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sessionID"];

    Sessions * mySessions = [[Sessions alloc] initWithID:sID andSessionStatus:sStatus andSessionDay:sDay andSessionDate:sDate andSessionTime:sTime andSessionName:sName andSessionSpeaker1:sSpeaker1 andSpeaker1Company:sSpeaker1Company andSessionSpeaker2:sSpeaker2 andSpeaker2Company:sSpeaker2Company andSessionSpeaker3:sSpeaker3 andSpeaker3Company:sSpeaker3Company andSessionSpeaker4:sSpeaker4 andSpeaker4Company:sSpeaker4Company andSessionSpeaker5:sSpeaker5 andSpeaker5Company:sSpeaker5Company andSessionSpeaker6:sSpeaker6 andSpeaker6Company:sSpeaker6Company andSessionDesc:sDesc andITSCECS:sITSCECS andSessionID:sSessionID];

    //Add our sessions object to our sessionsArray
    [sessionsArray addObject:mySessions];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sessionDate" ascending:YES];
    [sessionsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


    }



[self.myTableView reloadData];

}
```

Here's the code in numberOfSectionsInTableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    //return 1;

    if (tableView == self.myTableView) {
    return self.sessionsArray.count;
    }
    else
    {
        [self searchThroughData];
        return self.results.count;
    }


}
```

Here's the code in numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return sessionsArray.count;

    if (tableView == self.myTableView) {
    return self.sessionsArray.count;
    }
    else
    {
        [self searchThroughData];
        return self.results.count;
    }



}
```

Here's the code in titleForHeaderInSection:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[sessionsArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"sessionDate"];
}
```

I've only been working with Objective C for a couple months, so I'm probably overlooking something basic. Thanks for any help.

Comment: First of all, either your `numberOfRowsInSection` method is returning the number of sections in your data source, or your `numberOfSectionsInTableView ` is returning the number of rows in each section.

Comment: Please, please, please: use subscripting. `json[i][@"id"]` instead of `[[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]`

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sessionsArray` contains `Sessions` objects, but when you use it you're treating it like it contains dictionaries. You also use exactly the same code for the section count and the row count. So, it looks like you intend to have 2 sets / levels of data but currently you only have 1 and you're trying to use it for 2 things.

You need to decide what the `sessionsArray` is actually used for and keep it to that. What do the sections represent and how do you represent the rows in each section. Configure your data structure to match that.